# Opening ports in EC2

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, firewall, cassandra

I have an ec2 instance. I have opened a port in the security group for cassandra (9160) and have cassandra listening on it. If I use nmap on the instance, that port does not show up, and I cannot connect to the cassandra node remotely via cassandra-cli, cqlsh, or python-cql. This leads me to believe I am missing something in opening the port. So in general how does one open a port in an ec2 instance on the Ubuntu AMI?

Comment: iptables? It's set to drop anything but SSH by default.

Comment: iptables was empty when the instance was started. I added the following rule: `sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 9160 -j ACCEPT` and it is still not showing up

Comment: Did you clicked on the "apply" button ? ...

Comment: Yes I hit the "apply" button

Comment: Have you actually tried to connect to the port?

Comment: I have tried connecting a client to the cassandra database if that's what you mean.

Comment: Go through this checklist - 1. Where have you opened the port to? Public? 2. If yes, try telnet <ec2 instance's IP> 9160. If it connects, your port is open. If it does not, you've either not given the correct source (group, CIDR range) while opening, or there's a firewall running on the instance.

Comment: Okay telnet worked. Is there something I'm missing in the cassandra configuration?

Comment: I think It just took some time for the security settings to be updated

Answer (score 2):

Cassandra uses Thrift internally for RPC and gossips which works at 7199 protocol. If your 9160 port is opened on security groups and your cassandra is a cluster instead of single machine, then there is a chance that some internal dependent ports are not opened

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked [How can I open a port on my EC2 instance?](https://serverfault.com/questions/298124/how-can-i-open-a-port-on-my-ec2-instance)

You basically want to open up the firewall on the OS level, you also need to open up the security group for the AMI. Otherwise the port is blocked by Amazons security policy.